# как получить ODataQueryOptions с требуемым типом

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использую перегрузку метода контроллера ODATA

```
public IQueryable<TD> Get(ODataQueryOptions<OrdersViewsDto> options)
```

в которую мне приходят настройки для типа OrdersViewsDto

далее я получаю все сущности типа OrdersViews

```
var emp = db.OrdersViews.AsQueryable();
```

и когда пытаюсь применить опции переданные в запросе

```
    if (options.Top != null)
    {
        emp = options.Top.ApplyTo(emp , new ODataQuerySettings());
    }
```

в результате получаю ошибку

```
Не удается использовать выражение типа "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Data.Entities.OrdersViews]" для параметра типа "System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Data.Dto.OrdersViewsDto]" метода "System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Data.Dto.OrdersViewsDto] Take[OrdersViewsDto](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Data.Dto.OrdersViewsDto], Int32)"
```

На сколько я понимаю это оттого что из бд я получаю сущности типа OrdersViews а пытаюсь применить настройки для типа OrdersViewsDto. Вот собственно вопрос какие мне надо действия применить что бы избежать этой ошибки и получить например из объекта типа ODataQueryOptions объект типа ODataQueryOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сделал так, но если в OrdersViews полей меньше или несоответствие с OrdersViewsDto, то будут ошибки

```
var TEContext = new ODataQueryContext(options.Context.Model, typeof(OrdersViews), options.Context.Path);
var TEOption = new ODataQueryOptions<OrdersViews>(TEContext, options.Request);
```